Issues with positioning edge labels
I am having issues with positioning edge labels. I think I might be running conflicting packages but I'm not sure. My edge labels are not being positioned above, also I am unable to give my edges direction.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Vertex[x=-2,y=0]{x}
            \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{0110}
            \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{0100}
            \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{y}
            \Edge[label=+1,position=above,->](x)(0110)
            \Edge[](0110)(0100)
            \Edge[](0100)(y)
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You are using too many packages, which in worst case imposes update pain on everybody trying to compile your code. // Suggestion: comment out ALL packages, compile and uncomment packagewise until the compile works. E.g. graphicx isn’t needed here at all, and not all packages might coexist in peace, so to say. Will make your tikz experience smoother.

I also suggest to adopt this approach of separating your drawings from your main document: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721930/245790

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=-2,y=0]{x}
\Vertex[x=0,y=0]{0110}
\Vertex[x=2,y=0]{0100}
\Vertex[x=4,y=0]{y}
\Edge[label=+1, position=above, Direct](x)(0110)
\Edge[](0110)(0100)
\Edge[](0100)(y)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


